# LWC: How to iterate over a list of SObjects

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to create a lightning web component that will iterate through existing objects, however, I'm not sure how to get it to render.

Here is the Controller

```
public with sharing class RandomRecordAudit {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static map<string, string> getAllObjects(){
        map<string, string> objectList = new map<string, string>();
        for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
        {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
            objectList.put(objResult.getName(), objResult.getLabel());
        }
        return objectList;
    } 
}
```

Here is the JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAllObjects from '@salesforce/apex/RandomRecordAudit.getAllObjects';
export default class SObjectList extends LightningElement {

    @track objects;
    @track error;

    handleLoad() {
        getAllObjects()
            .then(result => {
                this.objects = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });

    }
}
```

And Here is the HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ApexImperativeMethod" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={objects}>
                <template for:each={objects} for:item="object">
                    <p key={object.Id}>{object.Name}</p>
                </template>
            </template>
            <template if:true={error}>
                <p>Error</p>
                <c-error-panel errors={error}></c-error-panel>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @BryanAnderson Comments are not for answering questions.

Comment: @sfdcfox my apologies, deleted

Comment: @BryanAnderson No worries, just suggesting that you add an answer :p

Answer (score 2):

Your response is returning like this:

```
{
    "Account":"Account",
    "Contact":"Contact",
    ...
}
```

Instead you should be returning your response in this way to fit your component code:

```
public static sobjRet[] getAllObjects(){
    map<string, string> objectList = new map<string, string>();
    sobjRet[] theList = new sobjRet[]{};
    for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
    {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
        theList.add(new sobjRet(objResult.getName(), objResult.getLabel()));
    }
    return theList;
}

public class sobjRet
{
    String Id;
    String Name;

    public sobjRet(String Id, String Name)
    {
         this.Id = Id;
         this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but the first "JSON" example was off. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is returning an Object, not a List. You can transform this afterwards in your JavaScript:

```
handleLoad() {
    getAllObjects()
        .then(result => {
            this.objects = Object.keys(result).map(key => ({ Id: key, Name: result[key] }));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });

    }
}
```

This is an alternative to the other answer, which approaches the change in Apex.